# Simulating a click on dynamically rendered React element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, onclick, use-ref

I am creating a geography game where you are supposed to click on a specific country on a world map - if you click on the right one, the country changes color and the game presents a new country to be clicked at. If the player doesn't know, he can click on a button which will show him the correct answer. For this, I want to simulate a click event, so that the same onClick() function is called as if you clicked on the correct country.

I am using D3, and the world map is made up of svg paths. Below is the code I thought would work, using the HTMLElement.click() method:

```
    function simulateClick() {

    // for each index in the nodelist, 
    // if the properties are equal to the properties of currentTargetUnit,
    // simulate a click on the path of that node

    let nodelist = d3.selectAll(".unit")
    for (let i = 0; i < nodelist._groups[0].length; i++) {
        if (nodelist._groups[0].item(i).__data__.properties.filename === currentTargetUnit.properties.filename) {
            console.log(nodelist._groups[0][i])
            // logs the correct svg path element
            nodelist._groups[0][i].click()
            // logs TypeError: nodelist._groups[0][i].click is not a function
        }
    }
}
```

I then looked at some tutorials which say that, for some reason I don't fully understand, you rather need to use React.useRef for this - but in all their examples, they put a "ref" value on an element which is returned from the beginning in the React component, like so:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const CustomTextInput = () => {
  const textInput = useRef();

  focusTextInput = () => textInput.current.focus();

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" ref={textInput} />
      <button onClick={focusTextInput}>Focus the text input</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

This obviously doesn't work because my svg path elements aren't returned initially. So my question is - how can I achieve this, whether using useRef or not?

Below are some previous questions I looked at which also did not help.
[Simulate click event on react element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091000/simulate-click-event-on-react-element)
[React Test Renderer Simulating Clicks on Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723937/react-test-renderer-simulating-clicks-on-elements)
[Simulating click on react element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241963/simulating-click-on-react-element)

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it - instead of calling the onClick() which was set inside the node I created a new clickevent with the help of the following code:

```
    function simulateClick() {
    let nodelist = d3.selectAll(".unit")
    for (let i = 0; i < nodelist._groups[0].length; i++) {
        if (nodelist._groups[0].item(i).__data__.properties.filename === currentTargetUnit.properties.filename) {
            var event = document.createEvent("SVGEvents");
            event.initEvent("click",true,true);
            nodelist._groups[0].item(i).dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```